# Keeping count in a recursive function

Tags: python, function, recursion, count, random-walk

I saw a few posts about keeping count of the number of iterations of a recursion but I couldn't follow or they didn't apply. Sorry if it is redundant though! I appreciate the help! I am trying to right a function for a random walk situation using a recursive function and keeping count of the number of steps. There is a visual component to it as well which tells me the actual function seems to be working but not the count part.

```
def rwSteps (start, low, hi ):
    """ returns the number of steps the sleepwalker took in order to finally reach the `lower or upper bound
    input: an integer start (starting position of the sleepwalker), an integer low (nonnegative, the smallest value our sleepwalker can wander to), and an integer hi (the highest value the sleepwalker can wander to)
    """
    count=0
    newcount = count +1
    ' '*start + '~'
    print (' '*start + '~')
    if low < start and start < hi:
        newstart = start + rs()
        newcount = count + 1
        return rwSteps(newstart, low, hi)
        return newcount



    elif start == low:
        finalcount = newcount +1
        return finalcount

    elif start == hi:
        finalcount = newcount +1
        return finalcount
```

Comment: `return newcount` isn't going to be reached because of the `return` statement above it

Answer (score 1):

Just have the function return the number of steps it and its descendants took:

```
def rwSteps (where, low, hi):
    print("{}~".format(' ' * where))

    if low < where < hi:
        return 1 + rwSteps(where + rs(), low, hi)
    else:
        return 0
```

however, this is a poor use of recursion - it is slow and very likely to run out of stack space and can easily be rewritten iteratively:

```
from random import randint

def rs():
    return randint(-1, 1)

def rw_steps (where, low, hi ):
    """
    Returns the number of steps the sleepwalker took
    before hitting the lower or upper bound

    Input:
        where: int    starting location of the sleepwalker
        low: int      >=0, the lower boundary
        hi: int       >low, the upper boundary
    """
    steps = 0
    while low < where < hi:
        print("{}~".format(' ' * where))
        steps += 1
        where += rs()

    print("Went out of bounds after {} steps".format(steps))
    return steps
```

Comment: What does steps += 1 and where += rs() do?